# Unable to download specific scala library in the SpringBoot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, scala, gradle, sbt

I am using springBoot:3.0.1 project with Java 17. Only one specific scala library is not downloading from the internal repo. But other libraries including Java and scala are downloaded.

Here is the gradle.build file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "$repositoryUrl";
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2"
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'scala'
}
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: "scala"

scala {
    version = "2.11.8"
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "$repositoryUrl";
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
    mavenCentral()
}


sourceCompatibility = '17'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    

    implementation "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.8"
    // this is the scala lib which is available in the repo.
    implementation 'com.myScalaLibrary.libok:my-lib-utils:1.0.1'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Now the scala library build in scala version 2.11.8 and java version 1.8

The error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.myScalaLibrary.libok:my-lib-utils:1.0.1.
Required by:
    project :
```

Comment: The URL is correct for the variable $repositoryUrl. And also other internal libraries are downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `repositoryUrl` variable for defining the URL of the maven repository from where the library would be downloaded. Where are you defining that variable? My guess is that the variable is not assigned and hence the repo URL is invalid.

You can try putting a breakpoint on the `url "$repositoryUrl";` line, run the gradle build in debug mode and inspect the value of the variable to make sure that it is indeed assigned.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The URL is correct for the variable $repositoryUrl. And also other internal libraries are downloaded.

Comment: In that case, there is an issue with your maven repository, or the artifact with the specified version doesn't exist in the repository because your build.gradle is correct.

Comment: version is correct.. it is downloaded in sbt project. I faced the issue only in springBoot project